# SPARQL: How to combine two subjects to use in CONSTRUCT?

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, rdfstore, sparqlwrapper

I am writing an SPARQL query where I am creating an RDF graph. I am using SPARQL CONSTRUCT. As a requirement of my work, I have to concatenate two subject values and used it with CONSTRUCT statement. I have tried to do following (my RDF graph is in Virtuoso):

```
prefix map: <#> 
prefix db: <> 
prefix vocab: <vocab/> 
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
prefix d2rq: <http://www.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/suhl/bizer/D2RQ/0.1#> 
prefix jdbc: <http://d2rq.org/terms/jdbc/>
prefix fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#> 

CONSTRUCT {
?p1 a d2rq:ClassMap
}

FROM <http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse>
WHERE 
{ 
<http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#DataSource> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
<http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#OracleDataSource>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#DataSource>.
?DB <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#OracleDataSource>.
<http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#HouseholdsWithinAdminRegion> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
?Table <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#HouseholdsWithinAdminRegion>.
BIND(CONCAT(?DB, ?Table) AS ?p1)
}
```

However, I am getting following Error:

```
Virtuoso RDF01 Error Bad variable value in CONSTRUCT: "http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#PROTOPOPhttp://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1" (tag 246 box flags 0) is not a valid subject, only object of a triple can be a literal
```

Please let me know how to solve it.

Comment: CONCAT returns a literal (string) value but is used in CONSTRUCT as a subject. In RDF only the object part of triples may contain literal values (as said in that error message).

Comment: If a triple ends up as being illegal in some way, literal-subject, bnode-predicate, the processor is supposed to simply skip that triple in the results.

Answer (score 3):

The error is basically saying that you are concatenating two URIs:

```
http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#PROTOPOP
http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#MIAMI_HOUSEHOLD_2009_1
```

into a literal. I don't know what you are exactly trying to do, but do you really want to concat the WHOLE URI or only the last part after the `#`? If you want to concat after the `#` you need to omit the namespace.

```
bind (concat(strafter(str(?s),str(fuse:)), strafter(str(?o),str(fuse:))) as ?p)
```

Even at this stage the result of the bind is a `literal` that you need to convert into a URI.

```
bind (uri(concat(strafter(str(?s),str(fuse:)), strafter(str(?o),str(fuse:)))) as ?p)
```

Generally I would simplify your query massively:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix fuse: <http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse#>
prefix owl:<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

CONSTRUCT {
    ?p1 a d2rq:ClassMap
}

FROM <http://www.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/fuse>
WHERE 
{ 
    fuse:DataSource a owl:Class.
    fuse:OracleDataSource  rdfs:subClassOf fuse:DataSource.
    ?DB a   fuse:DataSource.
    fuse:HouseholdsWithinAdminRegion a owl:Class.
    ?Table a  fuse:HouseholdsWithinAdminRegion.

    bind (uri(concat(strafter(str(?DB),str(fuse:)), 
        strafter(str(?Table),str(fuse:)))) as ?p)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However it is not working. It is giving me following error: "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Internal error: Built-in function is not implemented." Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: The query does not work: 1)there is a white space between ? and Table 2)the variable ?TD is not assigned.

Comment: @user2151087: it might be that the function STRAFTER is not implemented in the Virtuoso version that you're using.